# shift observation of one group into next group by id in R

Tags: r, date, dplyr, data.table, data-manipulation

Suppose I have a dataframe like so:

```r
contracts

        Dates Last.Price Last.Price.1  id        carry
1  1998-11-30      94.50        98.50  QS -0.040609137
2  1998-11-30      31.32        32.13  HO -0.025210084
3  1998-12-31      95.50        98.00  QS -0.025510204
4  1998-12-31      34.00        34.28  HO -0.008168028
5  1999-01-29     100.00       100.50  QS -0.004975124
6  1999-01-29      33.16        33.42  HO -0.007779773
7  1999-02-26     100.25       100.25  QS  0.000000000
8  1999-02-26      32.29        32.37  HO -0.002471424
9  1999-02-26      10.88        11.00  CO -0.010909091
10 1999-03-31     131.50       130.75  QS  0.005736138
11 1999-03-31      44.68        44.00  HO  0.015454545
12 1999-03-31      15.24        15.16  CO  0.005277045
```

I want to calculate the weights of each id in each month. I have a function that does this. I use dplyr to achieve this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

contracts <- contracts %>%
  mutate(Dates = ymd(Dates)) %>%
  group_by(Dates) %>%
  mutate(weights = weight(carry))
```

which gives:

```r
contracts 
        Dates Last.Price Last.Price.1  id        carry     weights
1  1998-11-30      94.50        98.50  QS -0.040609137 0.616979910
2  1998-11-30      31.32        32.13  HO -0.025210084 0.383020090
3  1998-12-31      95.50        98.00  QS -0.025510204 0.757468623
4  1998-12-31      34.00        34.28  HO -0.008168028 0.242531377
5  1999-01-29     100.00       100.50  QS -0.004975124 0.390056023
6  1999-01-29      33.16        33.42  HO -0.007779773 0.609943977
7  1999-02-26     100.25       100.25  QS  0.000000000          NA
8  1999-02-26      32.29        32.37  HO -0.002471424 0.184703218
9  1999-02-26      10.88        11.00  CO -0.010909091 0.815296782
10 1999-03-31     131.50       130.75  QS  0.057361377 0.057361377
11 1999-03-31      44.68        44.00  HO  0.015454545 0.015454545
12 1999-03-31      15.24        15.16  CO  0.005277045 0.005277045
```

Now I want the lag the weights, such that the weights calculated in november are applied in december. So I essentially want to shift the weights column by group, the group being the dates. So the values in November end up being the values in December and so on.

Now I also want the shift to match by id, such that if a new id is included, the group where the id first appears will have an NA in the lagged column.

The desired output is given below:

```r
desired
        Dates Last.Price Last.Price.1  id        carry     weights          w
1  1998-11-30      94.50        98.50  QS -0.040609137 0.616979910         NA
2  1998-11-30      31.32        32.13  HO -0.025210084 0.383020090         NA
3  1998-12-31      95.50        98.00  QS -0.025510204 0.757468623 0.61697991
4  1998-12-31      34.00        34.28  HO -0.008168028 0.242531377 0.38302009
5  1999-01-29     100.00       100.50  QS -0.004975124 0.390056023 0.75746862
6  1999-01-29      33.16        33.42  HO -0.007779773 0.609943977 0.24253138
7  1999-02-26     100.25       100.25  QS  0.000000000          NA 0.39005602
8  1999-02-26      32.29        32.37  HO -0.002471424 0.184703218 0.60994398
9  1999-02-26      10.88        11.00  CO -0.010909091 0.815296782         NA
10 1999-03-31     131.50       130.75  QS  0.057361377 0.057361377         NA
11 1999-03-31      44.68        44.00  HO  0.015454545 0.015454545 0.18470322
12 1999-03-31      15.24        15.16  CO  0.005277045 0.005277045 0.81529678
```

Take note of February 1999. CO has an NA because it first appears in February.

Now look at March 1999, CO has the value from Februray, QS has an NA only because the February value was NA (due to division by 0).

Can this be done?

Data:

```r
contracts  <- read.table(text = "Dates, Last.Price, Last.Price.1, id,carry
1998-11-30, 94.500, 98.500, QS, -0.0406091371
1998-11-30, 31.320, 32.130, HO, -0.0252100840
1998-12-31, 95.500, 98.000, QS, -0.0255102041
1998-12-31, 34.000, 34.280, HO, -0.0081680280
1999-01-29, 100.000, 100.500, QS, -0.0049751244
1999-01-29, 33.160, 33.420, HO, -0.0077797726
1999-02-26, 100.250, 100.250, QS,  0.0000000000
1999-02-26, 32.290, 32.370, HO, -0.0024714242
1999-02-26, 10.880, 11.000, CO, -0.0109090909
1999-03-31, 131.500, 130.750, QS,  0.0057361377
1999-03-31, 44.680, 44.000, HO,  0.0154545455
1999-03-31, 15.240, 15.160, CO,  0.0052770449", sep = ",", header = T)


desired <- read.table(text = "Dates,Last.Price,Last.Price.1,id,carry,weights,w
1998-11-30,94.5,98.5, QS,-0.0406091371,0.616979909839741,NA
1998-11-30,31.32,32.13, HO,-0.025210084,0.383020090160259,NA
1998-12-31,95.5,98, QS,-0.0255102041,0.757468623182272,0.616979909839741
1998-12-31,34,34.28, HO,-0.008168028,0.242531376817728,0.383020090160259
1999-01-29,100,100.5, QS,-0.0049751244,0.390056023188584,0.757468623182272
1999-01-29,33.16,33.42, HO,-0.0077797726,0.609943976811416,0.242531376817728
1999-02-26,100.25,100.25, QS,0,NA,0.390056023188584
1999-02-26,32.29,32.37, HO,-0.0024714242,0.184703218189261,0.609943976811416
1999-02-26,10.88,11, CO,-0.0109090909,0.815296781810739,NA
1999-03-31,131.5,130.75, QS,0.057361377,0.057361377,NA
1999-03-31,44.68,44, HO,0.0154545455,0.0154545455,0.184703218189261
1999-03-31,15.24,15.16, CO,0.0052770449,0.0052770449,0.815296782", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
```

weights function:

```r
weight <- function(vec) {
  neg <- which(vec<0)
  w <- vec
  w[neg] <- vec[vec<0] / sum(vec[vec<0])
  w[-neg] <- vec[vec>=0] / sum(vec[vec>=0])
  w
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you need dplyr's `lag` and `lead` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
contracts %>%
  group_by(Dates) %>%
  mutate(weights = weight(carry)) %>%
  arrange(Dates) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(w = dplyr::lag(weights)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 12 x 7
#    Dates      Last.Price Last.Price.1 id       carry   weights       w
#    <chr>           <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#  1 1998-11-30       94.5         98.5 " QS" -0.0406    0.617    NA    
#  2 1998-11-30       31.3         32.1 " HO" -0.0252    0.383    NA    
#  3 1998-12-31       95.5         98   " QS" -0.0255    0.757     0.617
#  4 1998-12-31       34           34.3 " HO" -0.00817   0.243     0.383
#  5 1999-01-29      100          100.  " QS" -0.00498   0.390     0.757
#  6 1999-01-29       33.2         33.4 " HO" -0.00778   0.610     0.243
#  7 1999-02-26      100.         100.  " QS"  0       NaN         0.390
#  8 1999-02-26       32.3         32.4 " HO" -0.00247   0.185     0.610
#  9 1999-02-26       10.9         11   " CO" -0.0109    0.815    NA    
# 10 1999-03-31      132.         131.  " QS"  0.00574   0.00574 NaN    
# 11 1999-03-31       44.7         44   " HO"  0.0155    0.0155    0.185
# 12 1999-03-31       15.2         15.2 " CO"  0.00528   0.00528   0.815
```

Notes:

- I used `dplyr::lag` instead of just `lag` because of the possibility of confusion with `stats::lag`, which behaves significantly differently than `dplyr::lag`. While most of the time it'll work just fine, it works until it doesn't ... and it doesn't usually warn you :-)
- This is lagging by `Dates` regardless of month. I'll assume that you are certain that `Dates` are always perfectly frequent. If you think there's the possibility in a gap (where lagging by-row is not correct), then you'll need to break out the year/month into a new field and join on itself instead of doing a `lag`.